# Error upon loading from a Login form. I think this has something to do with Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

After passing Login Form. it errors showing this.

```
Module Module1
Public rptdocument As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
```

Message Box:

> The assembly with display name 'BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried reinstalling this [CRforVS_13_0_2](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_2.exe) sadly no improvement.

How to fix this?

Comment: Searching in google:

http://geekswithblogs.net/TATWORTH/archive/2012/10/12/sandcastle-help-file-builder---october-2010-release.aspx

Answer (score 1):

add this to your app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```